# Getting data based on month and date excluding year

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have dob stored in mongodb in ISO date formate. And i want to get all the document which has date same as todays date and month. Is there any way to do this in mongo ?

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("nkada23e3dmw28392fh237"),
    "fullname" : "alan",
    "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("1980-09-12T00:00:00.000Z")},
   {
     "_id" : ObjectId("29hhda23e3dmw2ff392fh23r"),
    "fullname" : "alan1",
    "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("1993-10-11T00:00:00.000Z")},
   }
```

Comment: can you please post your collection and one document?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, There is a way to do that you can run this simple `aggregation` query like,

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                month: { $month: "$dateOfBirth" },
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$dateOfBirth" }
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                month: new Date().getMonth() + 1, //because January starts with 0
                day: new Date().getDate()
            }
        }
    ], function (err, data) {

    });
```

In `$projetct` you can pass other property that you want to select from your document. Like if you also want to select the `"fullname"` then your `$project` looks like below

```
$project: {
                month: { $month: "$dateOfBirth" },
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$dateOfBirth" },
                fullname: 1 // it can be true or 1
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, could you please explain it.

Comment: Ya Sure. Here what we are doing is first in $project we are selecting firstname and adding two properties called month and day from your dateOfBirth property. After selecting this properties we are matching that month and day with the current month and day Which we can get from new Date(). that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Date Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) to project only day and month and then apply filters.

```
day = 21
month = 11
coll.aggregate([{'$project':{"month": { "$month": "$dateOfBirth" },
                             "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$dateOfBirth" }}}, 
                {"$match":{"day": day, "month": month}}])
```